# how disable disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$document_root;

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, centos

I want Install a Script, company Owner of this script told in my NGINX

> disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$document_root;

is enabled,

How i should Disable it? cause i opened /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and i not Found it,
In which file i can found it?

Comment: Are there any `include` directives in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file?

Comment: Yes, below:
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-includes.conf;
    # Supplemental configuration
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-modsecurity-enable.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-defaults.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-gzip.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-ips.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-settings.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-vhosts.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-vhosts.conf;

Comment: They all need to be checked.

Comment: really i checked, but not found:(

Comment: `disable_symlinks` is switched off by default. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) for details. Unfortunately, it means that the script is failing for a different reason.